# Defining kernel size (c++ opencv)

Tags: c++, image, opencv, kernel

I am working with a project in opencv, where i am trying to segment and analyse an image from my webcam. So far the thresholding seems to be good, but as i am trying to reduce the noise in the picture i need to choose a kernel for the closing function that i am using. The problem is that i cannot find any good tutorial on how to do this. I have been looking into several methods but i have gotten nothing out of it.

Every opencv function i use i will have to know exactly what does, so i would like to avoid using the more advanced opencv functions.

Can anyone explain how to do this?

Regards Ulrik

Answer (score 1):

Here is good totorial about morphology operators.

http://aishack.in/tutorials/mathematical-morphology/

Comment: I am aware of how morphology works, i just do not really know how to change the kernel when using opencv 
but otherwise nice tutorial

Comment: Morphology element is just a matrix. With elements equal to 0 or 1. It should be odd elements in width and height. You can create any you want. The size of the matrix will be your kernel size. You also can use getStructuringElement for kernel generation. Suppose you use morphologyEx for morphology processing.

Comment: getStructuringElement did the trick, i was attempting to create my own kernel through my own code but couldnt get it to work, so thank you! :)